# Two tileContainers next to each other

Tags: xml, sapui5

I want to know if it is possible to put two TileContainers next to each other (side by side)? I have one that I want built based on one data source and the other from another source. Based on my data, I know the first one will have 4 tiles, and the second one will have 1 tile.

I saw this post ([SAPUI5 multiple sap.m.TileContainer in JS view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347073/sapui5-multiple-sap-m-tilecontainer-in-js-view)) where they put two tile containers one above the other, which I already have but I need to add this new one to the top row. I basically want the one row with the tiles from 'master' and 'new' on the same line of the screen.

Here is what I have but it is making three lines and not two:

```
  <TileContainer tiles="{/master}" height="25%" width="75%">
    <tiles>
      <StandardTile
        icon="sap-icon://dimension"
        type="Monitor"
        number="{count}"
        title="{cnt_type}"
        press="goToMasterPage"
        app:columnName="{cnt_type}"
        ></StandardTile>
    </tiles>
    </TileContainer>
  <TileContainer tiles="{/new}" height="25%" width="25%">
    <tiles>
      <StandardTile
        icon="sap-icon://inspection"
        type="Monitor"
        number="{newcount}"
        title="{type}"
        press="goToNewPage"
        app:columnName="{cnt_type}"
        ></StandardTile>
    </tiles>
  </TileContainer>
  <TileContainer height="25%" width="100%">
    <tiles>
        <StandardTile
            icon="sap-icon://upload"
            type="Monitor"
            title="Upload Download Information"
            press="goToUpload">
        </StandardTile>
        <StandardTile
            icon="sap-icon://download"
            type="Monitor"
            title="Create Download File"
            press="goToDownload">
        </StandardTile>
    </tiles>
  </TileContainer>
```

This is an EDIT after adding HorizontalLayout. Now I only get the tiles after the HorizontalLayout. It's like it isn't taking 50% height into consideration. Any ideas?

```
<Page title="Customer Outreach" enableScrolling="false">
    <l:HorizontalLayout height="50%">
                    <TileContainer tiles="{/master}" height="50%"  >
                        <tiles>
                          <StandardTile
                            icon="sap-icon://dimension"
                            type="Monitor"
                            number="{count}"
                            title="{cnt_type}"
                            press="goToMasterPage"
                            app:columnName="{cnt_type}"
                            ></StandardTile>
                        </tiles>
                    </TileContainer>

                    <TileContainer tiles="{/new}"  >
                    <tiles>
                      <StandardTile
                        icon="sap-icon://inspection"
                        type="Monitor"
                        number="{newcount}"
                        title="{type}"
                        press="goToNewPage"
                        app:columnName="{cnt_type}"
                        ></StandardTile>
                    </tiles>
                  </TileContainer>
    </l:HorizontalLayout>
                    <TileContainer height="50%" >
                        <tiles>
                            <StandardTile
                                icon="sap-icon://upload"
                                type="Monitor"
                                title="Upload Download Information"
                                press="goToUpload">
                            </StandardTile>
                            <StandardTile
                                icon="sap-icon://download"
                                type="Monitor"
                                title="Create Download File"
                                press="goToDownload">
                            </StandardTile>
                        </tiles>
                    </TileContainer>
</Page>
```

Comment: This has to be done by a parent layout container that arranges its children row-oriented like a `sap.ui.layout.Grid` or `sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout`. Don´t forget to set `enableScrolling` of your `sap.m.Page` to `false` as mentioned in the linked question.

Comment: would you by chance have an example I can follow? I tried adding a grid before I posted my question, but I must've done something wrong as nothing showed.

Comment: I tried using HorizontalLayout but I only get the second row of tiles. See above edit....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As disussed in the comments you can use a HorizontalLayout but when implementing this you will quickly find out, that this heavily affects the responsiveness of your application. However, a responsive version could base on using a [Grid](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.Grid.html) Layout. You simply assign a span of 12 for small and medium devices. Only on large screens you´re using the full width by showing both containers side by side:

```
var container1 = new sap.m.TileContainer({
  width : "100%",
  height: "350px",
  tiles : [new sap.m.StandardTile({
        icon : "sap-icon://play",
    title : "1st Important Tile"
  }),new sap.m.StandardTile({
        icon : "sap-icon://play",
    title : "2nd Important Tile"
  })]
}),container2 = new sap.m.TileContainer({
  width : "100%",
  height: "350px",
  tiles : [new sap.m.StandardTile({
        icon : "sap-icon://play",
    title : "1st Important Tile"
  }),new sap.m.StandardTile({
        icon : "sap-icon://play",
    title : "2nd Important Tile"
  })]
});

var gridContainer = new sap.ui.layout.Grid({
  defaultSpan : "L6 M12 S12",
  width : "100%",
  content : [container1, container2]
});
```

I´ve created a [JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/norobetoxo/edit?html,output) for you to test it.